# Integrating BIRT with Spring Remoting Error

Tags: spring, birt, spring-remoting

I am new to BIRT and I followed the following example to integrate BIRT with spring remoting example in devshare:

https://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt

I am getting the following exception:

```
Multiple exceptions occurred.
Hide Exception Stack Trace
Stack Trace:
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Wrapped org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition (#13)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.DataItemExecutor.execute(DataItemExecutor.java:75)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:249)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:273)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:89)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:159)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:118)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:103)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Wrapped org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition (#13)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException.wrap(DataException.java:123)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:1003)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.ExprEvaluateUtil.doEvaluateRawExpression(ExprEvaluateUtil.java:295)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.ExprEvaluateUtil.evaluateRawExpression(ExprEvaluateUtil.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDummyQuery$ResultIterator.(PreparedDummyQuery.java:532)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDummyQuery$ResultIterator.(PreparedDummyQuery.java:509)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDummyQuery$QueryResults.getResultIterator(PreparedDummyQuery.java:368)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.(QueryResultSet.java:98)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:168)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:83)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:285)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1947)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
... 80 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: Wrapped org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition (#13)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.wrapRhinoException(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:307)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:106)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:138)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:999)
... 91 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition (#13)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._inline__5._c_script_0(:13)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._inline__5.call()
   at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
   at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._inline__5.call()
   at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._inline__5.exec()
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:99)
... 93 more
```

The code in the designer:

```
importPackage(Packages.org.springframework.context);
importPackage(Packages.org.springframework.web.context.support );
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.spring.webviewer.example );

if( !reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getAttribute("attributeBean").isDesigner()){
var sc = reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getSession().getServletContext();

spring = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);

var mypojo = spring.getBean("client");

mypojo.getAllCars().get(0).getMake();
System.out.println("------------------------- mypojo.getAllCars().get(0).getMake();  == " + mypojo.getAllCars().get(0).getMake() );
}
```

Please let me know what cause this error.

Comment: Any help on this please.

Comment: I added the related tags to improve the visibility of this question.